# How to retrieve first false condition applied to a list

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a program in Haskell that assumes some input from stdin which should be validated according to some parameters.

From a bunch of conditions (e.g. conditions a,b,c,... ; each one returns a bool) applied to a list, how can I retrieve the first one that gets False?

```
E.g. 
condition a applied to list l = True;
condition b applied to list l = False;
condition c applied to list l = False;
condition d applied to list l = True;
condition e applied to list l = False;
... = doesn't matter
```

**The idea would be to apply some other function to list l knowing that condition b == False (in order to retrieve line error)**

Answer (score 7):

You should consider what your desired function will return if none of the applied function returns `False`. This is a classic use case for `Maybe`

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
firstFalse :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Maybe (a -> Bool)
firstFalse fs x = safeHead (dropWhile ($ x) fs)
    where safeHead []    = Nothing
          safeHead (a:_) = Just a
```

alternately,

```
firstFalse fs x = find (not . ($ x)) fs
```

Comment: You might like [`find :: (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find), as in, `firstFalse fs x = find ($x) fs`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That gets the test reversed, though.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yep, you're right. Luckily cdk fixed it silently when he added it to his answer. Thanks, cdk! =)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to test a bunch of conditions like that is to use guards. Except that those stop at `True` rather than `False`, but you can reverse it with `not`:

```
test l
  | not (a l) = ...result if a l fails...
  | not (b l) = ...result if b l fails...
  | not (c l) = ...result if c l fails...
  ...
  | otherwise = ...result if no condition fails...
```

Answer (score 1):

If `conds` is your list of conditions ( i.e. functions of type `[a] -> Bool`) and `list` is your list of items,
this expression returns the conditions which fail:

```
filter (\cond -> not (cond list)) list
-- also: [ cond | cond <- conds, not (cond list) ]
```

So to find the first condition which fails you can use:

```
firstFailure conds list =
    case filter (\cond -> not (cond list) of
        []        -> ... do something ...
        (cond:_)  -> ... cond is the first failing condition ...
```

Note you should handle the case where all conditions pass.